# Express custom GET/POST parameter binding nestjs / routing-controllers

Tags: express, nestjs

I have a `Controller` (nestjs / routing-controllers) and I'm passing a GET request the following way: `/collect?t=My-name`

`t` is actually a full name which I can't change.

Bellow im injecting `@QueryParams() data: CollectData`, Im looking for a way (like java strong and .net) to tell the controller that `fullName` is actually `t`.
Something like

```
export interface CollectData{
  @PropertyName('t')
  fullName: string
}
```

I'm expecting `fullName` to represent the `t` variable.

```
@JsonController()
export class CollectController {

    @Get('/collect')
    collect(@QueryParams() data: CollectData){ 
        return data.fullName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some sort of solution using the [class-transformer library](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#exposing-properties-with-different-names) and the `ValidationPipe` [given by Nest](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#the-built-in-validationpipe) (it also does transformations!) and have your `CollectionData` class (use a class so that the data can be serialized after transpiling, interfaces go away in JavaScript) look like this:

```js
// CollectData.ts
export class CollectData{
  @Expose({ name: 'fullName' })
  t: string
}

//Collect.controller.ts
@Controller() // Changed from JSONController to Controller
export class CollectController {

    @Get('/collect')
    collect(@Query(new ValidationPipe({ tranform: true }) data: CollectData){ //Changed from QueryParams to Query
        return data.fullName;
    }
}
```

OR in your `main.ts` add the `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ tranform: true })` to set the validation pipe to run against all your incoming requests